# Regex replacing only specific set of characthers

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have string like this:

```
Small Bubble Roll 3/16&quot; x 1400&#39; x 12&quot; Perforated 3/16 Bubbles 1400 Sq Ft Wrap
```

Note the signs:

```
&quot;

and

&#39;
```

I would like to replace these with single quote like this:

```
'
```

I have tried this regex:

```
Regex.Replace(inputText, @"(\s+|&quot;|&#39;)", "'")
```

But the result that I get is not what I want... How can I remove only specific set of characthers with single quote, like the ones that I've shown above?

Edit guys this is the input:

```
Small Bubble Roll 3/16&quot; x 1400&#39; x 12&quot; Perforated 3/16 Bubbles 1400 Sq Ft Wrap
```

Comment: Remove the `\s+|` You are replacing all the spaces.

Comment: I've played with http://regexr.com/3fg54 - I think you just have to escape some special chars - hope this helps

Comment: @Gunnar for some reason I'm not able to copy the entire expression, could you paste it here please? XD

Comment: @User987 it's not C# specific, just some pure regexp, could be something like `s/(\&quot\;|\&#39;)/'/g`

Comment: I suspect your input is not what you posted. Decode the text before the regex replacement. If it contained the entities, the `&quot;|&#39;`  regex would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to replace space so your pattern should be:

```
@"(&quot;|&#39;)"
```

And in code (also you should store result in some variable):

```
var str = "Small Bubble Roll 3/16&quot; x 1400&#39; x 12&quot; Perforated 3/16 Bubbles 1400 Sq Ft Wrap";
var res = Regex.Replace(inputText, @"(&quot;|&#39;)", "'")
```

Also, you can replace without regex:

```
var str = "Small Bubble Roll 3/16&quot; x 1400&#39; x 12&quot; Perforated 3/16 Bubbles 1400 Sq Ft Wrap";
str = str.Replace("&quot;", "'");
str = str.Replace("&#39;", "'");
```

Comment: Tried this, doesnt' works either, output stays as same :/

Comment: @User987, the code works correctly, I have tested it. Which result do you expect? I get `"Small Bubble Roll 3/16' x 1400' x 12' Perforated 3/16 Bubbles 1400 Sq Ft Wrap"`

Comment: @User987, could you explain why this code doesn't work for you?

Comment: Roma, I m really not sure, I did exactly like you wrote but the string remained the same way for some reason. I tripple checked it to see whether i made a logical mistake but still couldn't find why it didn't work =/

Comment: @User987, two solutions work and produce needed result. I don't know why you have accepted another answer, because there is `"` not `'`. But ok, it is good if it works for you

Comment: Roma, accepted urs =) ... I'm sure it was mistake on my end , maybe I've supplied the wrong string value

Comment: @User987, you shouldn't accept my answer, it doesn't work for you, it works for me, please accept answer which solved your problem

Comment: Just trying to show appreciation for the time it took you to write the answer and  to reply..  = D  And it indeed does work.. I've supplied the wrong string to the solution that you wrote, which is why it initially didnt

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` method from `System.Net`.

```
var result = WebUtility.HtmlDecode("Small Bubble Roll 3/16&quot; x 1400&#39; x 12&quot; Perforated 3/16 Bubbles 1400 Sq Ft Wrap");
```

Output of result:

> Small Bubble Roll 3/16" x 1400' x 12" Perforated 3/16 Bubbles 1400 Sq Ft Wrap

Comment: This actually works, but now I'm left with this: \" and \' ... How can I remove escape characthers now ?

Comment: Are you looking at the result in the debugger? It'll show escaped speech marks. If you actually use this string anywhere like in a label or output it to file it won't have the escapes. Ignore the debugger.

Comment: Equalsk, yes i' was looking at the debugger actually =D ... I store the value in DB... Hold on ill see what it outputs in another form when its stored in DB